# How to update the state of two independent components in react-native?

Tags: facebook, reactjs, react-native, reactjs-flux, react-native-listview

Update state of two independent components in react-native.

For example I have two components like contributorOne and contributorTwo, based on some event happening in contributorOne I want to update the state of contributorTwo data.

There is no parent child relationship in contributorOne and contributorTwo components, so can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide more context for your use case ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to explore an option such as [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) or another form of a flux architecture, which keeps a global state instead of using a per-component state. That way, when an action occurs in one component, it can dispatch an update to the global state which the other component can be subscribed to. There is no necessity for a shared parent relationship in this architecture, either, which seems to fit your requirements.

Comment: i don't know much about Redux there is any example how to use it with react native.

Comment: You can check out the Redux documentation [here](http://redux.js.org/), it works with React Native the same way it works with React. You can also check out other Flux stores such as [alt](https://github.com/goatslacker/alt) which follow many of the same concepts and also work with React Native.